# Does skirts in blue make any sense?

Tags: prepositions

**We have skirts in blue for $20.**

Does the in blue make any sense here? I just learned in as a prep has the meaning of wearing.

Comment: _In_ has many meanings; another of them is to refer to the available colours or types of a product on sale.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it makes sense.
The expression "skirts in blue" means blue-colored skirts.

About unrelated things, I think it's better to add "each" or "apiece" to after "$20" for clarification, and to change the verb "have" to a more unambiguous one--for example, "sell"--depending on what you want to make it mean.

Comment: "Have" and "sell" are not synonymous. I don't think "have" needs to be replaced by any other verb, it is quite unambiguous to me.

Comment: Given that there's a price listed, it's clear that whoever has the skirts intends to sell them.